# Get the values of all inputs with same class as an array

Tags: jquery

I have a group of inputs and I want to get the value of each one in array form or in any way that you will suggest. I am not very good at arrays.

```
$(elemnt).each(function(index, element) {
    $('#spc-name').val($(".spocName").val());
    alert($(".spocName").val());
});
```

the above line of code alert right thing for me but for a single input only but I have multiple inputs with `class="spocName"` so I want to get values of all and so that I could then save each in DB table in seperate rows.

Comment: you should use different class for each element

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If all your inputs share the same class say "class1" then you can select all such inputs using this

```
var inputs = $(".class1");
```

Then you can iterate over the inputs any way you want.

```
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    alert($(inputs[i]).val());
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this got accepted as it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: hi @RoryMcCrossan this answer is still related to question since this is an sample solution of how to iterate the same class array ... this method is too old

Comment: That's my point. The question asks how to put the values in to an array. This only loops through the found elements and shows the value in an `alert`. It also needlessly retrieves the Element object from a jQuery object, in order to create *another* jQuery object to get the value...

Answer (score 43):

To get the values of each element as an array you can use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
var valueArray = $('.spocName').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Or in ES6 (note that this is unsupported in IE):

```
var arr = $('.spocName').map((i, e) => e.value).get();
```

You can then use this array as required to save to your database - eg. as a parameter in an AJAX request.

The `get()` at the end is used to return the content within the jQuery object. Normally this is an Element object when selecting from the DOM, but in this case it's the Array we created using `map()`.

Comment: This is a great answer, especially since *map* is well supported today. See https://caniuse.com/?search=map

Answer (score 7):

```
var values = [];
$('.spocNames').each(function(){
    values.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value }); 
});
//use values after the loop
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 6):

you can user jquery ***each***  function ...

```
$('.spocNames').each(function(){
  alert(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  let itemarray = []
        document.querySelectorAll('.selector').forEach((item, index) => {
            console.log(item, index)

            itemarray.push($(item).val())

            item.addEventListener('input', (e => {
                itemarray[index] = $(item).val()
                console.log(itemarray)
            }))
        });
```

Explanation: Open an empty array, Use forEach respective to the selector that you want to receive values in. Use jQuery to put empty objects in the array as much as the length of selector. Whenever you input anything in the input field, it would modify it's original value and thus modifying the array itself.

Answer (score -1):

@mandip-darji's answer is totally acceptable and working.
I did little enhancement to it. So in my case, if you want a value of only one input field.

You can do something like below.

```
let keyWord = null;
    $('.searchinventory_input').each(function(){
       if(this.value){
           keyWord = this.value;
           return false;
       }
   });
```