# Change radio button's value based on one unique button of the same class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table, and imagine one column is based on radio buttons input, with two options: Yes and No.

All of the inputs of the column are under the same class.

Now, I would like that if any row the value is set to 'Yes', every input of the column will be set to 'Yes', and if any of the values is set to 'No' all the radio buttons will be set to 'No'.

So, finally is that any input from the column will change the rest of the values of the input.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what are the problems you are facing?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to begin, I visited some of the jquery documentation and ideally I'd want to itreate thruogh all of the radiobuttons of the same class, if any is changed change all of the values to that one. I don't know how to implement it though.

Comment: Ideally I'd want to do something like this  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247727/alert-the-values-of-all-inputs-with-same-class but that detects any change of all the inptus of the same class... IM kind of bad with jquery

Comment: Can you please post your HTML markup?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you're looking for is as follows:

1. Add a CSS class to each of your radio buttons that identifies their selected state.
2. Add some buttons, that when clicked, will set all radio buttons with the classes above to a particular state.
3. Add some JavaScript to hook the buttons up.

So step 1:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SomeProperty, "Yes", new { @class = "radio-yes" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SomeProperty, "No", new { @class = "radio-no" })
```

Step 2:

These don't have to actually be buttons - they can be radio buttons as you mentioned - but you get the point.  The main thing is being able to identify them and attach a function to handle the click event.

```
<button id="yes-to-all" type="button">Set all to Yes</button>
<button id="no-to-all" type="button">Set all to No</button>
```

Step 3:

```
$(function () {
    $('#yes-to-all').click(function () {
        $('.radio-yes').prop('checked', true);
    });
    $('#no-to-all').click(function () {
        $('.radio-no').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to check the value and class of any radio button (i.e. input) clicked:

HTML table:

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="rb1" value="Yes" class="someclass"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="No" class="someclass"> No</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="rb2" value="Yes"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="rb2" value="No"> No</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="rb3" value="Yes" class="someclass"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="rb3" value="No" class="someclass"> No</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="rb4" value="Yes"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="rb4" value="No"> No</td></tr>
</table>
```

Script block:

```
<script> 
$('input:radio').click(function()
{
    var $radios = $('input:radio');
    var checkedValue = $(this).val();
    alert(checkedValue);
    var checkedClass = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(checkedClass);
    $radios.filter('[value=' + checkedValue + ']').filter('[class=' + checkedClass + ']').prop('checked', true); 
});
</script>
```